# How to Search for Text Field in a Website with Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, search, hotkeys

How to Search for Text Field in a Page with Firefox?
What do I put in the find bar?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? A certain text field? Any text field? Can you give a concrete example please?

Comment: I mean searching for a text input area.
The one where you type stuff in.

Comment: Any specific one? Or just the first one you can find? Please, as I've already asked, give us a concrete example and [edit] your question.

Comment: OK, see that search bar over there on the top right of the site.
Imagine two, three of that hidden in a wall of text on a website.

How do I search for them with firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser's Search box cannot be used to find HTML elements (such as `<input type="text">`). Instead you can use the [Fox Input](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fox-input/) add-on for Firefox:

> This extension provides a hotkey to focus on the input field on a webpage. The default hotkeys are Alt-I (go to the next text input field) and Alt-J (go to the previous one), but you can change them in the setting window.

[image: 1]